# Lagrange multiplier?

Tags: probability-distributions, lagrange-multiplier, euler-lagrange-equation

Minimize $\int\limits_1^{+\infty} p\log x\,dx$, s.t. $\int\limits_1^{+\infty} p\,dx=1$ and
$\int\limits_1^{+\infty} p x\,dx = 2$.

$p$ is the density function of $x\in [1, +\infty)$.
If it were $\int\limits_1^{+\infty} p\log p\,dx$ it would be easy.

Comment: Those integrals are all divergent, are you sure you have copied it down correctly?

Comment: @darkmalthorp, $p$ is the density function of $x \in [1, +\infty)$. The integrals are convergent. The first integral just states that the integration of the density is 1, the second is the expectation of $x$ which is 2.

Comment: Ah it wasn't clear that it was meant to be function of $x$, thanks for updating.

Comment: presumably you also need $p(x) \ge 0$ for all $x\in[1,\infty)$, but not $p(x)\le 1$?

Comment: @Renard, yes, $p(x) \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infimum is $0$, but there is no probability measure, let alone one with a density function, which can achieve it. Let $\ \epsilon\ $ be any real number satisfying $\ 0<\epsilon<2\log2\ $, $\ b\ $ the unique positive real number such that
$$
\log(1+b)=\frac{\epsilon}{2}\ ,
$$
and $\ a\ $ the unique real number such that $\ a>e\ $ and
$$
\frac{\log a}{a}= \frac{\epsilon}{2}
$$
(I'm assuming here that the logarithm is the natural logarithm).
Then $\ 0<b<1\ $ and $\ 0< \frac{2-b}{2a-b-1} <\frac{1}{a+1}<1\ $.

Let $\ \pi= \frac{2-b}{2a-b-1}\ $ and $\ p_\epsilon\ $ be the density function defined by
$$
p_\epsilon(x)=\cases{\frac{1-\pi}{b}&for $\ 0\le x\le1+b$\\
\pi&for $\ a\le x\le1+a$\\
0&otherwise.}
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty xp_\epsilon(x)dx&=\frac{(1-\pi)}{b}\int_1^{1+b}xdx+\pi\int_a^{1+a}xdx\\
&= \frac{(1-\pi)\left(b^2+2b\right)}{2b}+\frac{\pi(2a+1)}{2}\\
&=\frac{(2a-3)(b+2)}{2(2a-b-1)}+\frac{(2-b)(2a+1)}{2(2a-b-1)}\\
&=2\ \text{, and}\\
\int_1^\infty\log xp_\epsilon(x)dx&=\frac{(1-\pi)}{b}\int_1^{1+b}\log xdx+ \pi\int_a^{1+a}\log xdx\\
&\le(1-\pi)\log(1+b)+\pi\log(1+a)\\
&\le\frac{(1-\pi)\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\log a}{a}\\
&\le\epsilon\ .
\end{align}
In short, by concentrating nearly all of the weight of the density function near $1$, and the rest over a suitably chosen interval, it's possible to satisfy the the required constraints and make the integral $\ \displaystyle\int_1^\infty\log x\,p(x)dx\ $ (which must be positive) as close to zero as you please.